# Azure devops pipeline buildtag not set

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm using a powershell script in my pipeline to set a build tag. See snippet of Powershell script below:

```
Write-Host "Version: $Version"
Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$Version"
```

This step in the pipeline fails, I get the following output:

```
Version: 0.0.1+
Major: 0
Minor: 0
Patch: 1
Reason: Manual
Async Command Start: Add Build Tag
Build '4510' has following tags now: Manual
Async Command End: Add Build Tag
Async Command Start: Add Build Tag
Async Command End: Add Build Tag
##[error]Not Found
```

My version = "0.0.1+". It seems to fail because of the + sign. When I do it manually in the GUI I can add "0.0.1+" as a tag, it not is not working when doing it in the YAML file. How can I do it in the YAML file?

Comment: Please add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your YAML pipeline as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` tag is not supported in logging command `##vso[build.addbuildtag]build tag`.

The GUI used [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/tags/update-build-tags?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to update the build tag, which is different with logging command.

You can confirm in network trace:
[image]

To update the build tag(`0.0.1+`) in yaml, you can follow above rest api in DevOps powershell task:

sample code:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $body = '{"tagsToAdd":["0.0.1+"],"tagsToRemove":[]}'
      $header = @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"}
      $Uri = "$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProjectId)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/tags?api-version=7.1-preview.3"
      Write-Host $Uri
      $buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -ContentType "application/json" -Uri $Uri -Body $body -Headers $header
      write-host $buildresponse
```

[image]

You can use variable for the tag value if needed.

```
$body = '{"tagsToAdd":["$(tag)"],"tagsToRemove":[]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, it works!! I now use the API to set the build tags. I use the following code to set the build tags:

```
    $body = @{
      tagsToAdd = @($Version, $Reason)
      tagsToRemove = @()
    } | ConvertTo-Json
    $header = @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"}
    $Uri = "$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProjectId)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/tags?api-version=7.1-preview.3"
    Write-Host $Uri
    $buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -ContentType "application/json" -Uri $Uri -Body $body -Headers $header
    write-host $buildresponse
```

Comment: Glad to know it works for you! In order to let others who have the similar question with you know how you resolved it more clearly, it's suggested that you [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) according to How does accepting an answer work. Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).